# Add to element as divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, so here's my code:
HTML:

```
 <h2>Header</h2>
    <div id="results1" class="results">
        <h1>Results 1</h1>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 (function() {
     var results = document.getElementById('results1');
     var drink = [ 'Rum', 'Vodka', 'Whiskey', 'Beer' ];
 })();
```

I need to add the drinks to the results element as divs.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written yourself to attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: You can iterate though `fruit` array and create HTML wrap each fruit to  `div` and append to `results` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple `for` loop to iterate over the `array`, and then append each item to the results `div`.

```
 for (var i = 0 ; i < fruit.length; i++) {
     results.innerHTML += "<div>" + fruit[i] + "</div>";
 };
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DqX9j/)**

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript:

```
(function() {

  var results = document.getElementById('results1');
  var fruits = [ 'Rum', 'Vodka', 'Whiskey', 'Beer' ];

  for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){

    var fruit = document.createElement('div').innerHTML = fruits[i];

    results.appendChild(fruit);

  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CzaC/)**
 try like this

```
var parent = $("#results1");
var fruit = ['Rum', 'Vodka', 'Whiskey', 'Beer'];

$.each(fruit, function (i, val) {

    parent.append("<div id=" + val + " >" + val + "</div>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

**js**

```
(function() {
    var results = document.getElementById('results1');
    var fruit = [ 'Rum', 'Vodka', 'Whiskey', 'Beer' ];


    for(var i=0; i<fruit.length; i++){
        var div = $("<div>" + fruit[i] + "</div>");
        $(div).appendTo("#results1");
    }

})();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7BC5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var results = document.getElementById('results1');
    var fruit = [ 'Rum', 'Vodka', 'Whiskey', 'Beer' ];
    for(var i=0; i<fruit.length;i++){
        $("#results1").append('<div>'+fruit[i]+'</div>');
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit.forEach(function(value,index){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = value;
    $("#results1").append(div);
});
```

Comment: Some additional explanation would benefit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

```
(function() {
    var results = document.getElementById('results1');
    var drink = [ 'Rum', 'Vodka', 'Whiskey', 'Beer' ];
    results.innerHTML += '<div>' + drink.join('</div><div>') + '</div>';
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the for loop you could use for javascript
and incorporated it into your html.

```
 var drink = ["Rum", "Vodka", "Whiskey", "Beer"];
 for (index = 0; index < drink.length; ++index) {
     text += drink[index];
 }
```